# Batch script to sort the largest file

Tags: sorting, batch-file, cmd

I am currently trying to make a script that will ask up to 9 variables, verify their sizes and then give me the largest one. It needs to work with less variables too. Also, it has to be done from a second script that is called from the first one.

I'm a student and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.

Comment: Please read [ask] for details as to how best to provide us with a framework to help you.  If you don't already have a `batch-file` framework to work with and provide us, we can't really help you well.

Comment: variables or files? `dir /o:s` will sort the files by size.

Comment: When you say you're trying to make a script, it means you have something, so don't be shy, without it we can't help you fix it. In addition, you're not clear about your variables, are you looking for the biggest variable, or are all the variables file names and your after the largest of those file sizes.

Comment: I'm still at the thinking stage, I haven't really figured out how to write it. The user has to enter file names (1 to 9) then it finds the largest one by file size then it displays back the largest one. Maybe it's sounds easy but we haven't seen much for batch files, only the basics. I tried: dir /o:s . But I don't know how to get the size in a variable then sort it to get the largest.

Answer (score 0):

most of the job can be done with just `dir` (with proper switches). Add some code for getting input from user and a `for` to get the output of `dir` and you're done:

```
@echo off
setlocal
REM get filenames:
:loop
set "new="
set /p "new=Filename (or leave blank): "
if defined new (
  set files=%files% %new%
  goto :loop
)

REM list them sorted by size (for debugging/checking)
dir /a-d /os %files% |findstr /v /b /c:" "
echo/

REM get the last (biggest) of them:
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /os /b %files%') do set biggest=%%a
echo biggest file is: %biggest%
```